# App launch "outside" of the unity-panel launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I created a .desktop file for the "exploTux" game (see https://gna.org/projects/explotux/ ), but the launcher does not match the app window.

To be clear: when I click the launcher on the Unity panel, the game launches and work fine but the game window is represented by a new "launcher" in the panel.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: launchers in the Unity-panel].

The upper launcher is my .desktop, the other is the one that appears when the game is running (note that there is only one opened window and that the panel icon show 3 arrows as in "3 open windows"...).
I tried to pin this new launcher but then it makes unity crashy.

Where do you think the problem is?
I tested on both Natty and Oneiric.

Here is the code of my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=exploTux
Comment=A Bomberman like in 3D
Exec=/usr/games/exploTux
Icon=explotux
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Game;ActionGame;
```

edit: I have a similar problem in Gnome-Shell:

[image: Same in Gnome-Shell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the game's "executable" actually launches something else, or that the game is changing the window title/class or something of the sort, and thus confusing libamf (and by extension Unity). I don't think there is anything you can do to fix that (directly), but you can report a bug against Unity.

Bug reports of this type are usually appreciated by the developers.

Comment: Thanks, I reported a bug against bamf. It's here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/858288